# Elastic search shards - total, successful, failed

Tags: elasticsearch

This is the results

```
{
  "_index": "vehicles",
  "_id": "123",
  "_version": 2,
  "result": "updated",
  "_shards": {
    "total": 2,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "_seq_no": 1,
  "_primary_term": 1
}
```

for query

```
PUT /vehicles/_doc/123
{
  "make": "Honda",
  "color": "Blue",
  "HP": 250,
  "milage": 24000,
  "price": 19300.97
}
```

on elastic search 8.

May I know

1. The `total` shards (which is 2) does it include primary shard + replica shard?
2. The `successful` shards - I supposed that's the primary shard where the put is written into - can it be more than 1?
3. The `failed` - I supposed it's the failed primary shard?

Answer (score 3):

As explained in the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#docs-index-api-response-body) for the Index API response body:

- `_shards.total` tells you how many shard copies (**primaries + replicas**) the index operation **should** be executed on
- `_shards.successful` returns the number of shard copies the index operation succeeded on. Upon success, `successful` is at least 1, like in your case. Since [by default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-wait-for-active-shards), write operations only wait for the primary shards to be active before proceeding, only 1 is returned. If you want to see 2, then you need to add `wait_for_active_shards=all` in your indexing request
- `_shards.failed` contains replication-related errors in the case an index operation failed on a replica shard. 0 indicates there were no failures.

Answer (score 0):

Search API official documentation if needed to someone: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html

1. `_shards.total:` Total number of shards that require querying, including unallocated shards.
2. `_shards.successful`: Number of shards that executed the request successfully.
3. `_shards.skipped:` Number of shards that skipped the request because a lightweight check helped realize that no documents could possibly match on this shard. This typically happens when a search request includes a range filter and the shard only has values that fall outside of that range.
4. `_shards.failed:` Number of shards that failed to execute the request. Note that shards that are not allocated will be considered neither successful nor failed. Having failed+successful less than total is thus an indication that some of the shards were not allocated.